# Ubuntu Error with Database but not on Debian

Tags: mysql, 17.04, debian, phpmyadmin

So I have two server and both have different OS one is Ubuntu 17 and the other one is Debian 9 Minimal (Minimal because my hosting service only has that or Debian 7). So both have the same html file and js file and php file. Every time I lunch my app on the Ubuntu server I get this error:

```
[2017-11-02 18:06:58.514] [ERROR] [default] - Strange error
[2017-11-02 18:06:58.515] [ERROR] [default] - { Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD:                 Field 'pskinsurl' doesn't have a default value
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protoc                ol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences                /Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Proto                col.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:1                2)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103                :28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.                js:145:48)
    at Connection.query (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:2                5)
    at Query._callback (/var/www/Bot/cf.js:3293:26)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequence                s/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/proto                col/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Q                uery.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Proto                col.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:1                2)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103                :28)
  code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1364,
  sqlMessage: 'Field \'pskinsurl\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO games SET expire = 1509662218, cassetids = \'12530890030\',                 csteamid = \'76561198114317007\', cname = \'KnottyCord\', cavatar = \'https://st                eamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1d/1d3f34eee812968fd5                548f36ee281265373ddf91_full.jpg\', cskinsurl = \'-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWw                KGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsVFx5KAVo5PSkKV4xhfG                fKTgVvIXlxNPSwaOmMLiGwzgJvJMniO-Zoo_z2wXg-EVvfSmtc78HsNoy\', cskinsnames = \'Gam                ma 2 Case\', cskinsprices = \'0.03\', cskins = 1, ctp = 0.03, cpick = \'t\', tcr                eated = 1509660418.494, hash = \'adb9037cfd700a24544d4d774189a223\', bot = \'bot                1\'' }
```

And on the Debian one I don't get this error.

So in the end I would like to Use Ubuntu because I'm more familiar with it.

Thank you If you need additional information just ask me.

PS: To anyone telling me that I have to specify a specific value in my code, well no because it needs to be at none because my "bot" will set the value by him self. The value depends on what the user is doing and there is a million possibilities and can't make a line of code for all of them.

Comment: Server side, there is minimal differences between Debian and Ubuntu so perhaps staying with Debian is the best option. You would need to post your code for debugging, I suggest you pastebin them. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values

Comment: Is there a way to make change ubuntu so it accept a none value in the database. Because on debian im not able to get the site working I keep getting 521 Webserver down even tho apache is started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clearly stated:

> Field \'pskinsurl\' doesn\'t have a default value

You try to insert a record in a table without specifying a value for the above mentionned field and no default value is known in the table definition.  The difference you observe between the two servers can come from a difference in the database server you use or in the definition of the table.
So you have 3 options:

1. Add a value for that field in the INSERT statement.
2. Modify the definition of your table
3. Make sure you use the same database server on both servers.

Comment: That's my code to update the database:  pool.query('UPDATE games SET `psteamid` = "", `pname` = "", `pavatar` = "", `pskinsurl` = "", `pskinsnames` = "", `pskinsprices` = "", `pskins` = "", `ptp` = "", `trade_token` = "" WHERE `trade_token` = ' + pool.escape(row[i].tid), function(aaa,bbb) {
                    if(err) throw err;

Comment: Is there a way to set the value to none on ubuntu? Cause the program absolutely need the value of none to work

Comment: Strange: in code code snippet of your question, you have an 'INSERT' statement and here, an UPDATE.  Why?  Anyway, your question merely is a question of programming language than a question of Ubuntu.  For Java, I cannot answer.  For Python, I would use: `pskinsurl = None` to put the field at a null value.  Of course, your table definition must allow 'Null' values for that field, otherwise, independently of OS, your DBMS will refuse 'Null' values.